# How does thread pool manage work item with worker thread when one task is blocking?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, clr

My question is based on this article [Internals of Windows Thread](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/662735/Internals-of-Windows-Thread)

We can see that for every thread in system, operating system create one thread kernel object. Operating systems use these thread kernel objects for managing and executing threads across the system

[image]

Every 20 milliseconds or so, operating system thread scheduler looks at all the thread kernel objects currently inside Ready Queue (doubly linked list). Thread scheduler selects one of the thread kernel objects and loads the CPU's registers with the values that were last saved in the thread's context.

[image]

And CLR's thread pool architecture is

[image]

Each worker thread has its own local queue, and when a worker thread schedules a Task, the Task is added to calling the thread's local queue.

With this background, let's say .NET ThreadPool has some worker hreads as picture above shows. Let's say Worker Thread 1 has some worker items queueing in the Local Queue 1. The current task the Worker Thread 1 executing is blocking for a couple of seconds(wait for a signal to arrive etc or it is executing a long running task).

My question is,

**A**.can Worker Thread 1 temporarily stop executing this blocking task and switch to execute another task in its local queue, then after the new task finishes and then come back to execute the long running task again. If this is the case, how can the long running task's context state be saved?for example, we need to store the registers' values into the Thread Kernel Object 1, but when Worker Thread 1 starts to execute another task, then the original task's state saved in the Thread Kernel Object 1 will get lost

or

**B**.Worker Thread 1 has to finish this long running task first then it can execute other task in its local queue. But this is inefficient as Worker Thread 1 wastes a couple of seconds that it could have used to execute other task.

Comment: Use async/await.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A. Can Worker Thread 1 temporarily stop executing this blocking task and switch to execute another task in its local queue, then after the new task finishes and then come back to execute the long running task again. If this is the case, how can the long running task's context state be saved?for example, we need to store the registers' values into the Thread Kernel Object 1, but when Worker Thread 1 starts to execute another task, then the original task's state saved in the Thread Kernel Object 1 will get lost

It really depends on how you're executing Thread 1's code.

If you're executing the code as a synchronous block on Thread 1, there's no way to stop a blocking task to resume work on the same thread, unless you're doing some long running operations that frequently and *explicitly* allows time for other code to execute on the same thread(see below)

The other way in C#, you can execute code in asynchronous method that uses `await` or explicitly allow other code to run through the use of certain methods in the [`Thread`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread?view=net-5.0) class such as [`Thread.Yeild`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.yield?view=net-5.0) / [`Thread.Sleep`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.sleep?view=net-5.0#System_Threading_Thread_Sleep_System_Int32_).

When you use these methods or the `await` operator the thread relinquishes the remainder of its time slice to any thread of equal priority that is ready to run. If there are no other threads of equal priority that are ready to run, execution of the current thread is not suspended(except for `.Sleep()` where it's not scheduled at all for the given time frame).

The way these 'time slices' are given away or suspended without losing the state of a long running operation is through the use of compiled [state machines](https://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/understanding-c-sharp-async-await-1-compilation) that are generated at compile time or on-the-fly(rarely).

These state machines break down the written code, which may **appear** as an un-interruptable block of code - into their raw IL and breaks it apart so it can execute in discrete blocks and maintain state between the times it's allotted to run by the scheduler.